# how to programmatically remove all added rows via initial values in antd dynamic form

Tags: reactjs, antd, dynamic-forms

After I set initialvalues to the dynamic form, it automatically adds rows according to the given length. Next, what I need to do is remove all added rows using a button click or a function.

Comment: please add the code for what you have already tried

Comment: Have you tried with https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List ?